# I want to find solutions to PDE using Fourier sine series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**ODE:**

Let $u = u(t, x):\ [0, \infty)\times [0, L] \to \mathbb{R}$ be unknown and let $u_0 = u_0(x):\ [0,L] \to \mathbb{R}, u_1 = u_1(x):\ [0,L] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given. Let $L > 0, c > 0, 0 \leq \mu < \frac{\pi c}{L}\ $be constants.

At this point, I would like to solve the following ODE:
$$
\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{d^2b_n}{dt^2}(t) + \frac{2\mu}{c^2} \frac{db_n}{dt}(t) = -\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} \right)^2 b_n(t),\\
b_n(0) = b_{0,n},\\
\frac{db_n}{dt}(0) = b_{1,n} 
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**What I know:**

Consider the characteristic equation
$$\lambda^2 + 2\mu\lambda + c^2\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2 = 0.\\
\therefore \lambda = -\mu \pm\sqrt{\mu^2-\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2}
$$
so the ODE solution is
$$
b_n(t) = e^{-\mu t}\left\{ b_{0,n}\cos{\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2 -\mu^2}t\right)} + \frac{b_{1,n}+\mu b_{0,n}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2 -\mu^2}} \sin{\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2 -\mu^2}t\right)}\right\}.
$$

If $\mu=0$, then
$$
b_n(t) = b_{0,n}\cos{\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L}t \right)} + \frac{L}{n\pi c}b_{1,n}\sin{\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L}t \right)}
$$.

If $\mu= \frac{\pi c}{2L}$, then
$$
b_n(t) = e^{-\frac{\pi c}{2L}t}\left\{b_{0,n}\cos{\left( \sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\pi c}{L}t \right)} + \frac{2Lb_{1,n}+\pi cb_{0,n}}{2\pi c \sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}}b_{1,n}\sin{\left( \sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\pi c}{L}t \right)}\right\}.
$$

- When $\mu=0$, the PDE is the wave equation? How do the Fourier coefficients $b_n$ behave depending on these two values of $\mu$? Could you please consider the difference?

Comment: What have you tried? For each $n$, it is just a [constant coefficient second order linear ODE](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/2%3A_Higher_order_linear_ODEs/2.2%3A_Constant_coefficient_second_order_linear_ODEs). Remember that if you want someone to help you, you need to write more contexts: where did you get the problem, what are your thoughts, to name just a few. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you for all your accurate advice. Please check the corrected version.

Comment: Great. Please do the same thing on your future questions. So, this problem is a little bit complicated in calculations. First of all, your characteristic equation should be $\lambda^2 + 2\mu\lambda + c^2\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^{\color{red}{2}} = 0$, so the roots are $\lambda = -\mu \pm\sqrt{\mu^2-(\frac{n\pi c}L)^2}$. If $n\neq 0$, then $\mu^2<(\frac{n\pi c}L)^2$ so the roots are not real numbers, the general solution is $b_n(t)=C_{1,n}e^{-\mu t}\cos(\sqrt{(\frac{n\pi c}L)^2-\mu^2}t)+C_{2,n}e^{-\mu t}\sin(\sqrt{(\frac{n\pi c}L)^2-\mu}^2t)$. Use initial data to determine the constants.

Comment: For $n=0$, the roots are real: $0$ and $-2\mu$. If $\mu\neq 0$, then these two roots are distinct and the general solution is $b_0(t)=C_{1,0}+C_{2,0}e^{-\mu t}$; if $\mu=0$, then these two roots are equal. So the general solution is $b_0(t)=C_{1,0}+C_{2,0}t$. Now we can find the solutions of the original ODE systems. I know you want a detailed answer with accurate expressions of solutions. But forgive me, I'm just lazy. I believe the above method is enough to get an accurate answer. You just need to be careful on your computations.

Comment: $n$ is a natural number$(n \in \mathbb{N})$, but do I need to consider the case when $n=0$?

Comment: I think $n$ may take all integers (including negative integers and $0$), if you are using the method of separating variables to find solutions of a PDE. If you are sure about the range of $n$, I mean, if you are sure that $n\neq 0$, then you just don’t need to consider the case where $n=0$, of course.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you!
So, I have a new question. What is the behavior if $\mu$ is specifically given for the solution obtained? I have added this information and would appreciate it if you could enlighten me.