# The behavior of Fourier coefficients obtained from PDE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The following questions are relevant:
[I want to find solutions to PDE using Fourier sine series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498957/i-want-to-find-solutions-to-pde-using-fourier-sine-series-expansion)

**ODE:**

Let $u = u(t, x):\ [0, \infty)\times [0, L] \to \mathbb{R}$ be unknown and let $u_0 = u_0(x):\ [0,L] \to \mathbb{R}, u_1 = u_1(x):\ [0,L] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given. Let $L > 0, c > 0, 0 \leq \mu < \frac{\pi c}{L}\ $be constants.

At this point, I would like to solve the following ODE:
$$
\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{d^2b_n}{dt^2}(t) + \frac{2\mu}{c^2} \frac{db_n}{dt}(t) = -\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} \right)^2 b_n(t),\\
b_n(0) = b_{0,n}, \frac{db_n}{dt}(0) = b_{1,n} 
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**ODE solution:**
$$
b_n(t) = e^{-\mu t}\left\{ b_{0,n}\cos{\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2 -\mu^2}t\right)} + \frac{b_{1,n}+\mu b_{0,n}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2 -\mu^2}} \sin{\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{n\pi c}{L}\right)^2 -\mu^2}t\right)}\right\}.
$$

If $\mu=0$, then
$$
b_n(t) = b_{0,n}\cos{\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L}t \right)} + \frac{L}{n\pi c}b_{1,n}\sin{\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L}t \right)}.
$$

If $\mu= \frac{\pi c}{2L}$, then
$$
b_n(t) = e^{-\frac{\pi c}{2L}t}\left\{b_{0,n}\cos{\left( \sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\pi c}{L}t \right)} + \frac{2Lb_{1,n}+\pi cb_{0,n}}{2\pi c \sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}}b_{1,n}\sin{\left( \sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{\pi c}{L}t \right)}\right\}.
$$

**Question:**

- When $\mu=0$, the PDE is the wave equation? How do the Fourier coefficients $b_n$ behave depending on these two values of $\mu$? Could you please consider the difference?

Comment: This doesn't directly address the question, but one thing I recommend for these types of equations is nondimensionalizing the variables. This will make the analysis much cleaner as you don't have so many constants running around. In this case, defining $\tau = \pi c t/L$, $m = L\mu/(\pi c)$, and $b_n(t) = \beta_n(\pi c t/L)$ makes the equation the much neater: $\beta_n''(\tau) +2 m \beta_n'(\tau) + n^2 \beta(\tau) = 0$.